# why does the fan come on when I turn my key on?

Tags: motorcycle, fan, cooling, kawasaki, vulcan

I have a 1998 Vulcan 800A. When I bought it the fan kicked on after I rode it for a while. It quit working so I replaced the fan switch and sensor. Now it comes on as soon as I turn the key on. Does that sound right?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: So how are these connected? Most systems have the sensor acting as the switch ie temperature controlled...